# effective method for text mining in vba/excel

Tags: excel, vba, text, powerquery, mining

I have a huge text file, consisting of about 18.000 samples of text, seperated by a consistent number of forward slaches: ////////////////////

```
Example:

////////////////////
P11/000568

name: john
age: 18
hobbies: cycling, drawing

////////////////////
P12/000894
name: eva
age: 19
hobbies: football, soccer, baseball
```

I want to "mine" this text file for the word "soccer", so that every time the program "sees" this word, a new line is created in excel, containing the name of the subject and the code above

```
      A            B           age
1 P12/000894       eva         19
```

I have tried some code (vba- excel, reading in every chunk of text into an array) but since the txt file is so large, my pc is melting when running the code.
Any ideas on the best method (vba-excel preferentially, powerpivot/powerquery??)

Thanks
C

Comment: Please post the code you have --- post it on this site (above) if the code has errors or a problem. Post it on [Codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) if your code works with no errors but you're requesting performance improvements and comments.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: a [video](https://youtu.be/WyGQthLYSaI) is now available explaining 2 approaches.
The fast approach is in the code below.

In Excel / Power Query it can be done with the following code:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Input"]}[Content],
    Typed = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Text", type text}}),
    RemovedBlankRows = Table.SelectRows(Typed, each not List.IsEmpty(List.RemoveMatchingItems(Record.FieldValues(_), {"", null}))),
    Combined = Table.FromColumns({List.Skip(RemovedBlankRows[Text],4),List.Skip(RemovedBlankRows[Text],1),List.Skip(RemovedBlankRows[Text],2),List.Skip(RemovedBlankRows[Text],3)},{"Original","Code","Name","Age"}),
    Filtered = Table.SelectRows(Combined, each Text.Contains([Original], "soccer")),
    Removed = Table.RemoveColumns(Filtered,{"Original"}),
    Transformed = Table.TransformColumns(Removed, {{"Name", each Text.RemoveRange(_, 0, 6), type text},{"Age", each Int64.From(Text.RemoveRange(_, 0, 5)), Int64.Type}})
in
    Transformed
```

Comment: Hi. Your code has one serious drawback: you assume there is fixed number of parameters per record and they come in fixed order.

Comment: @Eugene: well observed! So a prerequisite for my code to work is that the number and order of parameters must be fixed, That's a limitation indeed and, if the prerequisite is not met, it's a drawback as well, even worse: in that case my code can't be used.

Comment: Marcel, on the other hand it seem to work faster than mine on large (2M rows) dataset as Table.Distinct and Table.Pivot are very resource-consuming.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you want in PowerQuery:

```
let
    //Delimiter is REQUIRED, Default of "," messes the table!
    Source = Csv.Document(File.Contents("C:\Users\Eugene\Desktop\test.txt"),[Delimiter="`", Columns=1, Encoding=1251, QuoteStyle=QuoteStyle.None]),
    Split = Table.SplitColumn(Source,"Column1",Splitter.SplitTextByEachDelimiter({":"}, QuoteStyle.Csv, false),{"Parameter", "Value"}),
    FilteredExcessiveRows = Table.SelectRows(Split, each ([Parameter] <> "" and [Parameter] <> "////////////////////")),
    AddCode = Table.AddColumn(FilteredExcessiveRows, "Code", each if _[Value] = null then _[Parameter] else null),
    FillDown = Table.FillDown(AddCode,{"Code"}),
    RemoveDuplicates = Table.Distinct(FillDown, {"Code", "Parameter"}),
    Filtered2 = Table.SelectRows(RemoveDuplicates, each ([Value] <> null)),
    Pivot = Table.Pivot(Filtered2, List.Distinct(Filtered2[Parameter]), "Parameter", "Value"),
    Filtered3 = Table.SelectRows(Pivot, each Text.Contains([hobbies], "soccer")),
    RemoveHobbies = Table.RemoveColumns(Filtered3,{"hobbies"})
in
    RemoveHobbies
```